# Get input checkbox toggle state with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I would like that whenever you click on a checkbox, a value is printed to the console that corresponds to the state of the checkbox (`on`/`off`). I know there are threads with similar titles but all those I've seen don't have clear examples.

Here's what I got so far 
(Turn on `Console` and click `Add library`, `JQuery1.8.3`):

[Attempt 1](http://jsbin.com/urodit/111/edit)

This only prints when the page is loaded, I want it to print whenever I click on it.

[Attempt 2](http://jsbin.com/urodit/112/edit)

This snippet toggles an on and off value whenever I click on the checkbox, but the box doesn't display the tick symbol anymore when it is toggled on.

Comment: Why are you loading two versions of jQuery in your examples?

Comment: I wasn't even aware of that.

Comment: just to explain why attempt#2 doesn't work(although it should): jQuery internally calls `event.preventDefault()` for the click-event. The default-action for a click on a checkbox is toggling the checked-property. Because of that you shouldn't use `toggle()` on elements where you want to proceed with the default click-action(e.g. links, submit-buttons etc. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen to the change event.

```
$("#box").change(function(){  
    console.log(this.checked); 
    // console.log( this.checked ? 'on' : 'off' ); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#box").change(function() {
  console.log($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy, you need to use the .val() inside of a click event. Here is the code:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        console.log( $(this).val() );
    } else {
        console.log('no');
    }
});
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/atomicpages/F4yaU/). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$('#box').click(function()
{
    if ($('#box').is(':checked')){ 
        console.log("on"); 
    }else{ 
        console.log("off");
    }
});
```